# Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} x^{-n}e^x=\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} x^{-n}e^x=\infty$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I'm allowed to use that $e^x> \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$

So far I have said the following:

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}.$

$$x^{-n}e^x>\frac{x^{-n}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{x}{(n+1)!}$$

Where do I go next?

Comment: is $n$ a constant? Then the statement follows immediately from your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go anywhere, if (as remarked in the comments) $n$ is constant. If you really want to write it formally,
\begin{equation}
\forall M>0\ \exists N>0: x>M\Rightarrow \frac{x}{(n+1)!}>N
\end{equation}
namely, picking $N=M/(n+1)!$.